# Connecting to Windows 7 file system over local network is very slow

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-sharing

Essentially, connecting to a Windows 7 file system from another Windows 7 system over local network is very slow. 
The system I am trying to connect to is awake and the drive is running when I attempt to connect.
It's not a DNS issue as ping resolves the target instantly.
Once I am connected, the operation speed is acceptable. The initial connection however can take minutes.
Is there a way to diagnose this? What is causing this incredibly long delay?

Comment: Is either computer joined to a domain?

Comment: Nope -- Purely workgroup mode for both.